# SQL on duplicate of 2 values set 3rd value

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using a SQL table that represents what account can use which currencies,
it looks like this:

| id(pk) | accountNumber | currency | active |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 | USD | 0 |
| 2 | 1234 | EUR | 1 |
| 3 | 7777 | USD | 1 |

the meaning is that account '1234' can use EUR only (USD is not active).

I want to create an SQL statement that adds new lines to the table(to add new currencies to the system or unable account to use a currency), but in case the 'accountNumber - currency' pair already exists, change the 'active' column to active instead of adding a new line.

what is the best way to to that ?
should I use If in this statement of "on duplicate"?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a compound unique key on accountnumber/currency? if so use insert..on duplicate key. If not add one. NB you can't use if in an insert statement - you could in a procedure as an alternative to insert..on duplicate key.

Comment: If user cannot have more than one active currency then active currency is an attribute of the user, not of a currency. And the reference on active currency must be moved to users table.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways you can achieve this by executing a query like this:

```
BEGIN

DECLARE @accountNumber as int, @currency as nvarchar(10), @active as bit;
SET @accountNumber = 1234
SET @currency = 'USD'
SET @active = 1

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [AccountInfo] WHERE accountNumber = @accountNumber 
AND currency = @currency) 
   INSERT INTO [AccountInfo] (accountNumber,currency,active) 
   VALUES (@accountNumber,@currency,@active)
ELSE
   UPDATE [AccountInfo] SET active= @active where accountNumber = @accountNumber 
AND currency = @currency

END
```